# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to play gif images in my flutter app using chewie and video player but I get the above error.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

gifs aren't videos, you can use the standard image widget and they'll show just fine. You can take a look at the documentation here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html

short answer:

```
Image.network('...');
```